# NestJS > TypeORM Mapping complex entities to complex DTOs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

Im using class-transformer > `plainToClass`(entity, DTO) to map entities to DTO's

I've also implemented the associated transform.interceptor pattern described [here](https://github.com/scalio/nest-workshop-backend/blob/master/src/common/interceptors/transform.interceptor.ts).

Then I use `@Expose()` on members of my DTO's. This works great but I have a limitation, I need to map member DTO's in my parent DTO and this isn't happening, see simple example below

```
@Exclude()
export class ParentDTO{

  @Expose()
  pMember2 : string;

  @Expose()
  pMember2 : ChildDto[];
}

@Exclude()
export class ChildDTO{

  @Expose()
  cMember2 : string;
}

export class ParentEntity{
  pMember1 : number;
  pMember2 : string;
  pMember3 : string;
  pMember4
 : Child[];
}

export class ChildEntity{
  cMember1 : number;
  cMember2 : string;
  cMember3 : string;
}
```

Now if I run `plainToClass(parentEntityFromDB, ParentDTO)` I was hoping to get the following

```
ParentDTO{
  pMember2 : string;
  pMember2 : ChildDto[];
}
```

However, what I am getting is

```
ParentDTO{
  pMember2 : string;
  pMember2 : Child[]; //Including all original members
}
```

Basically plainToClass(entity, DTO) is not automatically mapping members to match the given DTO type.

Is there a way to do this or is this a limitation of the method??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the nested type with `@Type`:

```
@Exclude()
export class ParentDTO{

  @Expose()
  pMember2 : string;

  @Expose()
  @Type(() => ChildDto)
  pMember2 : ChildDto[];
}
```

With the `@Type` decorator, class-transformer instantiates a class for the given property when `plainToClass` is called. Otherwise, the nested property will stay a plain javascript object and hence your `@Exclude` will not be used.